# Count number of line breaks in Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets, count, line-breaks

Cell value represents a list.
Line breaks in cell represents number of items in list
Need to identify number of items in list.

Answer (score 7):

**Correction**

The formula is incorrect for empty cells, use instead:

```
= LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), "")) + 1 * COUNTA(A1)
```

Assuming your cell is `A1`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this link figured it out:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4785-excel-count-newlines.html

Equation where A2 is the cell you want to count the line breaks:

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with the count formula:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,(CHAR(10))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `COUNTA` and does the right thing for empty cells:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,(CHAR(10)))))
```